# (Python 2.7) Regex Replace with similar character in replacement string as in pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"/")
a = "a/b"
```

I tried

```
re.sub(pattern, '\/', a) 
#(also, a.replace('/', '\/'))
#output
a\\/b
```

What I want is

```
a\/b
```

Comment: Sounds like you want `a.replace('/','\\/')`

Comment: Try: ```x=re.sub(pattern, '\/', a) ``` and then ```print(x)```. It's already correct

Comment: Your code is working - https://rextester.com/NNB40155

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski I have python 2.7 and it's not working. maybe it would be working in 3.x.

Comment: yeah, if you print the results, you get `a\/b` and not sure why you are using `re.sub` instead of `pattern.sub('\/', a)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a.replace('/', '\\/')
```

the first `\` is an escape character, so you need to type it twice to have the real `\`.

Comment: what version of python you are using?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.7, but it works also in 2.7

Comment: yes, you are correct. Actually I was running in jupyter and without print() statement, otherwise it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use if it's not compulsory to use regex:

```
a = "a/b"
a=a.replace("/","\/")
print(a)
```